# How to make UISlider stepless

Tags: swift, uislider

I am wondering if there is a way to make a UISlider move smoothly like the one in music App. Without steps and jumps. Just move till the end. I am currently using `CADisplayLink` to update the slider, the only problem is that the slider just jumps to the next value even when `animated` is set to true. This looks bad with values under 2min.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused by your question, but if your slider is very erratic and jumps to values the user did not set, I would recommend increasing the size of the element on your view controller. 
If that doesn't work, you could scale your `minimumValue` and `maximumValue` by a factor of ten and then divide by ten when actually doing calculations with your UISlider. What I mean by that is:

1. multiply min and max values by 10
2. Keep a variable of the actual value you want to use
3. Save your value and divide by 10 whenever the user sets a new value in the UISlider

Comment: Even if I multiply the minimum and maximum value of UISlider that would mean that the video/audio would end before the the slider ends.